# Typo: in word "fon" Spellchecker inspection helps locate typos and misspelling in your code, comment and literals, and fix them in one click

Tags: android

Toolbar подключаю `android:background="@drawable/fon"` со следующим кодом, именно где подключаю горит красным и выводит сообщения:

`Typo: in word "fon" Spellchecker inspection helps locate typos and misspelling in your code, comment and literals, and fix them in one click`.

Что это значит и как исправить это?

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#4093A3"
            android:angle="90" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: это сообщение не является сообщением об ошибке. Это ворнинг о том ,что слова *fon* не существует в англ. языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сообщение не является сообщением об ошибке. Это предупреждение о том ,что слова *fon* не существует в англ. языке

Comment: Согласно комменту @metalurgus и здравому смыслу.